# I want to get a count of unique entries in the Apache error logs on

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, grep, sed, logfiles

When viewing Apache's log files there are a lot of error message repeated. I would like to find out which error messages are most frequent and which are unique.

I would like a simple script that can provide me with a count of the different unique lines.

I know of Perl/Python/etc., but I would prefer to use built-in tools such as `cut`/`find`/`grep`/`sed`, etc.

I can get a simple list of entries using `sed`. The following displays a list of unique error messages:

```
$ sed -e "s/\[.*\]\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" error.sml.log | sort -u
Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
client denied by server configuration
Digest
File does not exist
request failed
```

This works to count the number of occurrences. It's just not that useful as it does not show what the counts relate to:

```
$ sed -e "s/\[.*\]\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" error.sml.log | sort -u | xargs -I{} grep -oc {} error.sml.log
1
3886
2
6091
20
```

I would like the output to look more like this:

```
1    Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
3886 client denied by server configuration
2    Digest
6091 File does not exist
20   request failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e "s/\[.*\]\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" error.sml.log | sort | uniq -c
      1  Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
   3886  client denied by server configuration
      2  Digest
   6091  File does not exist
     20  request failed
```

There is a tool which does exactly that uniq. I wish I had found this a couple of hours ago.

There are a couple of useful options such as 
 uniq -d only show lines with more then 1 entry

```
$ sed -e "s/\[.*\]\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" error.sml.log | sort | uniq -cd
   3886  client denied by server configuration
      2  Digest
   6091  File does not exist
     20  request failed
```

uniq -u only show uniq lines only 1 entry

```
$ sed -e "s/\[.*\]\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" error.sml.log | sort | uniq -u  
  Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Now I can process our billion line log files and make some sense of what is going on in side them.

Comment: If I had been on I could've told you. It comes up a lot, a few searches should've found it (that's how I learned about it, I wanted to know how many times conky threw an error into my .xsession-errors file, it was over 182,000 times!)